# How to store an item/image in a specific coordinate in Cordova/Ionic?

Tags: javascript, android, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I am trying to make a simple Augment Reality app like pokemon go using Ionic, with a feature to view a pokemon appearing on top of a camera.

I made it work using a SDK called [ezAR](https://www.ezartech.com/) and my current output looks like this:

[image]

The problem here is that wherever I go or point the camera, the pokemon image is just static and what I wanted to do is to use a cordova plugin like Geolocation to fit my needs. I know how to use it but I don't know where to start.

The goal here that I want is to make the pokemon show at a specific coordinate. Is that possible with those plugins only? Any guide/help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This is enough to the client side. But you will need build a API that will be consumed by your app (client/server architecture). The app with geolocation plugin help will send to the server the user's position from time to time, then the server will check if the user is near enough to a registered point. If it's true,  the server will respond with the point's informations (pokemon, or anything)  and the app will start the camera and will render what you need, with the server passed information and the eZar's help.